# Замена одного блока другим CSS

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как можно реализовать. Есть блок, при наведении на него, он меняется на другой.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите на псевдокласс [:hover](http://htmlbook.ru/css/hover). Но при таком подходе можно будет поменять только некоторые css-свойства блока. Для настройки более тонкого поведения надо использовать javascript.

**Update**
Только что увидел вашу картинку. Если сильно не извращатся, то hover тут не поможет. Используйте javascript.

**И еще update**

Можно [так](http://jsfiddle.net/tm41ef67/) попробовать. А еще лучше [так](http://jsfiddle.net/1qy2xwp4/)